# SharedWithUsersId property in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am trying to retrieve list of user IDs which have access to a document which was previously shared. When I execute URL like this on Office 365:

https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('%2Ffolder%2Fsectest1')/ListItemAllFields?$select=SharedWithUsersId

I get following reply:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
  <id>abfd6b41-f5ea-4e34-b10b-c3e3e3ab9dd3</id>
  <category term="SP.Data.CARA_x0020_CheckoutItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5eb48869-c58d-4507-81d3-211baedeb04f')/Items(1133)"/>
  <title/>
  <updated>2017-09-01T09:05:25Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
    <d:SharedWithUsersId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
        <d:element>43</d:element>
        <d:element>42</d:element>
    </d:SharedWithUsersId>
   </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

And d:SharedWithUsersId property contains IDs 43 and 42 - this is exactly what I want.

I tried doing the same on SharePoint 2013 (on premises) and unfortunately there is no such property in the response:

```
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:Id>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:ID>
      <d:ContentTypeId>0x01010012C728C8DDD38B4EBB2016D1414713F6</d:ContentTypeId>
      <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-09-01T19:54:15</d:Created>
      <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:AuthorId>
      <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-09-01T19:54:15</d:Modified>
      <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:EditorId>
      <d:OData__CopySource m:null="true"/>
      <d:CheckoutUserId m:null="true"/>
      <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
      <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">a589b149-1dc1-4ad5-8b9e-008343c5ebc5</d:GUID>
      <d:Title>Installation Guide</d:Title>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
```

In both cases the document is stored in a folder which has broken inheritance with the parent folder.

Does it mean that SharePoint 2013 (on premises) does not provide such information? Is there any other way to find out with whom a document was shared with?

I tried RoleAssignments service but this gives me information about all users which have access to the document, it includes also those users which are site owners etc. this is not what I want...

Thanks!
Karol

Comment: The `SharedWithUsersId` does not exist in SharePoint 2013 on-premises as of today.